# I`ve read that MVC can find out its size class environment via this method in UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, size-classes, uitraitcollection

`let mySizeClass: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass = self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass`

and the return value will be an enum .Compact or .Regular (or .Unspecified).

When I try it in code compiler shows me a warning: `Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> MyViewController' has no member 'traitCollection'`.

Please tell me what is wrong. I`m studying Standford's course on iTunesU and I have this example from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are putting the code in the wrong place, namely at the top level of the view controller declaration. Your code needs to go *inside a method*.